# Best way to tell if two files are the same?

Tags: c#, file

If I transfer a file over the internet from computer A to computer B using C# using one of the many ways to do file transfers with .NET, What is the best way to tell if the file on computer A and computer B is the same?

I am thinking that MD5 hashes would be a good way to tell. It seems like that is a widely accepted way to tell. However, I am just double checking to see if there is not a better way out there hidden in the .NET framework.

Thank you
Tony

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MD5 is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

CRC32 or Adler32, which are a lot faster then MD5. You should use MD5 if you need to check if file was manipulated with malicious intent. If there is no need to, than it's overkill.

Comment: It depends on the computers involved - I'd expect most of the time to be spent on IO unless you're using really slow processors, so the algorithm used (assuming it only needs to read the data once) shouldn't make much odds.

Answer (score 2):

SHA2 (SHA256, SHA512) algorithms are better than MD5 for many reasons.

- They are more resistant to collisions, an important concern for large files. While MD5 can detect changes to the content of the file, it is more likely that two large files can end up having the same MD5.
- They are FASTER to compute. This may seem strange, but SHA algorithm are accelerated both by chipsets and OS implementations. The algorithms themselves are easier to parallelize as well. As a result, native implementations of SHA or SHA2 algorithms in Vista+ are much faster than the equivalent MD5 algorithm.
- They use a larger block size which means they can work on large file blocks at a time. I/O time can add up when processing large files.

The native implementations in .NET are [SHA256Cng](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256cng.aspx), SHA384Cng and SHA512Cng. Instead of instantiating them explicitly, you can define them as the default algorithm to use when hashing using the [< cryptoClass >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzccd30c.aspx) element in your configuration file.

After you do that, you can just write `HashAlgorithm.Create()` or `SHA256256.Create()` to create the native instance.